# Classification in a known subset of a set of categories

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

Let C = c_1, ..., c_{52} be the 52 cards of a game.
We have the hand of a player X = x_1, ..., x_{13} and we want to predict the card that will be played by using a basic feed-forward neural network classifier.

The input is an array of size 13 and the output is an array of probabilities of size 52 for which element i is the probability of the output being the card c_i.

But obviously we want to force element i to be 0 if the player doesn't have the card in his hand.

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to force this. During training, the examples only have as played car a card which was in the players hand. The network will soon understand that predicting a card which is not in the players hand is wrong.

If you are keen in forcing this on your prediction. You could always just consider the classes regarding the playable cards during prediction (argmax on the playable classes only).